# Why the python module newspaper3k only return 0 articles for tencent, sina and wallstreetcn?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, python-newspaper, sinaweibo

The newspaper3k library is amazing. I am addicted on it.

May I ask, why the Source and build() only return 0 articles from most of the china financial news page?

Any problem in my code?

```
from newspaper import Article, Source

url='https://wallstreetcn.com/live/global'

result=newspaper.Source(url,language='zh')

result.build()

result.size()

0
```

Answer (score 1):

I run your code and received a different result, maybe you run into cache problem. try to add `memoize_articles=False`, see:

```
import newspaper

url='https://wallstreetcn.com/live/global'
result = newspaper.Source(url, language='zh', memoize_articles=False)

result.build()
result.size()
>>> 2
```

you can find the documentation [here](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/quickstart.html#article-caching)